# Using undertow handler chaining, how do I catch exceptions in an http request that was dispatched to a worker thread?

Tags: java, error-handling, httprequest, undertow

I'm using the undertow security framework to handle an http request. Details on that can be seen here : http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html#security.

My handler chain uses an error handler first with a try catch block that is designed to catch any errors during the handling of the http request. This worked prior to implementing the undertow security handlers.

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    try {
        next.handleRequest(exchange);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        //code
    }
```

It will hit the error handler first, then it will go through the security handlers which will dispatch the request. Then it reaches MyLogicHandler which will throw an exception based on a null parameter.

Any exception thrown will be caught by the try/catch seen here : https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/Connectors.java#L199

This always throws a 500 error, which is not what I want. The purpose of the ErrorHandler is to let me set the response code based on the types of errors.

Is there a way to get my ErrorHandler to catch exceptions in requests that are dispatched to the XNIO worker threads?